# How can I make this code into a class so I can reuse it?

Tags: php

I am using xPaw's Minecraft Query:
https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query

I made a function to it so I can connect to our servers, however the problem is that we have multiple servers, so I have to copy and paste the function and rename the function and other parts of the code so it can connect to the other servers.

```
function get_MQ_Query() {
  define( 'MQ_SERVER_ADDR', '1stserver.com' );
  define( 'MQ_SERVER_PORT', 25565 );
  define( 'MQ_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  // require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
  require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  // Display everything in browser, because some people can't look in logs for errors
  Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
  Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
    $Error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }
  return $Query;
}
```

I'd like to pass an array to the class and call it

```
$mcQuery = new mcQuery();
// Define servers
$server = [
    '1server' => '1.server.com',
    '2server' => '2.server.com',
    '3server' => '3.server.com',
    '4server' => '4.server.com'
];
```

Calling it would look like this:

```
Status: <?php echo $mcQuery->getStatus($server['1server']); ?>
```

I'm not sure how to get around into doing this though. How can I get something like that?

Comment: Hi, ceadreak. I'm still a bit new to classes and such. Can you answer with an example?

Comment: I will write an example

Comment: No, I haven't. I wanted to try to make this into a class rather then a bunch of functions since there will be different type of functions such as getPlayers and getVersion.

Comment: class McQuery { function getStatus() { code here } } http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: One thing to make note is variables are called properties and functions are called methods in OOP. So keep that in mind when reading the documentation.

Comment: Lastly (because I just noticed it) you probably shouldn't be defining constants in a function.  If you try to run that function twice, it will fail. You should be using variables (properties)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

class YourClass {
    protected $_query;

    public function __construct($host, $port, $timeout=1) {
        $Timer = MicroTime( true );
        $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );
        try {
            $Query->Connect( $host, $port, $timeout );
        } catch( MinecraftQueryException $e ) {
            $Error = $e->getMessage();
            echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
        }
        $this->_query = $Query;        
    }

    public function getPlayers() {/*...*/}

    public function getVersion() {/*...*/}

} 

$connect = new YourClass('1.server.com', 25564);

/* etc ... */
```

Comment: Thank you, part of this is new to me. There are no parameters in YourClass yet you added it in  new YourClass('1.server.com', 25564);. Is this the __construct magic? Is it apart of the class?

Comment: The OP didn't want it in __construct(), he wanted a separate function for getStatus.

Comment: Yes, there is one parameter (property), You can implement it as you wish, it's just an example to how to declare and use an object. Now, you can pass in your construct only the host and the port, set them as class properties and write a getQuery() method. OOP bring you many possibilities. Please, read the doc ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
class MyMcQuery
{
    protected $port;
    protected $timeout;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->port = 25565;
    $this->timeout = 1;
    }

    public function query( $server )
    {          
      $Timer = MicroTime( true );
      $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

      try
      {
        $Query->Connect( $server, $this->port, $this->timeout );
      }
      catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
      {
        $Error = $e->getMessage();
       echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
      }
      return $Query;
    }    
}
```